Is there an equivalent of AWS Lambda Extension/Wrapper script for Google Cloud Functions
I am hoping to have an outer script that can trigger google cloud functions and modify my runtime. is there something available similar to AWS Lambda Function Extensions?
I have went through documentation but have not found any references of how I can do so

If you want to use custom runtime on Cloud Functions, I strongly recommend to use Cloud Run instead. You can build your own container with all the requirements that you need. And it's the future of serverless on Google Cloud. have a closer look to it!
